# How to get the primitive from a boxed Object

Tags: android, object, reflection, callback, primitive-types

When using custom callbacks (like `android:onClick`) the actual method is called using something like

```
mHandler.invoke(context, View.this);
```

According to the doc on `invoke`:

> Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object receiver, Object...
>   args) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,
>   InvocationTargetException
>
> Returns the result of dynamically invoking this method. Equivalent to
>   receiver.methodName(arg1, arg2, ... , argN).
>
> If the invocation completes normally, the return value itself is
>   returned. **If the method is declared to return a primitive type, the
>   return value is boxed**. If the return type is void, null is returned.

What does "boxed" mean? If the actual method returns a `boolean` how can i get it from `Object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Boxing, otherwise known as wrapping, is the process of placing a primitive type within an object so that the primitive can be used as a reference object. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Boxing)

The boxed primitive, in your case, would be the [Boolean object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html). I believe you should be able to cast a returned, non-null object straight to a Boolean object or a boolean primitive.

Comment: `boolean b = (Boolean) mHandler.invoke(context, View.this);` works fine, casting from `Boolean` to `boolean` is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Use `booleanValue()` on `Boolean` object, to get `boolean` primitive